# hardcode pg_query select on postgreSql

Tags: php, postgresql

when i tried to hardcode pg_query query on php, but result is :

> resource(3) of type (pgsql result)

```
PHP code :
$result = pg_query($db_connection, "SELECT * FROM datatest");
var_dump(pg_fetch_all($result));
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Done, this is need to fetch the array first with pg_fetch_all !!

try this, and it will work :

```
var_dump(pg_fetch_all($result));
```